# MYSQL Query to get date difference

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have a table Transaction with following column and data

```
id  transaction_date trans_type account_id agents_id transaction_date price miles
1   2012-02-08       Buy        1          1         2010-02-08       0.016 12000
2   2012-03-01       Sell       2          2         2012-03-10       0.256 -2000
3   2012-03-27       Buy        3          3         2012-03-27       0.256 10000
4   2012-03-28       Sell       4          4         2012-03-28       0.589 -11000
5   2012-03-29       Buy        5          5         2012-03-29       0.87  25000
6   2012-03-29       Sell       6          6         2012-02-29       0.879 -12000
7   2012-04-01       Sell       7          7         2012-04-01       0.058 -15000

  Account Table
  id    Program_id
  1     1
  2     1
  3     2

  Program table
  id      Abbreviation
  1       AA
  2       AC

  Agents table
  id      Name
  1       Bob
  2       Ben
```

I want to get first sell date and first buy date to get average days before a transaction is sold, to get days transaction is in inventory, so it should be

```
  (Sell date)2012-03-01 - (Buy date)2012-02-08
```

i m trying this

```
SELECT 
    case when t.trans_type ='Sell' then transaction_date end as SellDate
   ,case when t.trans_type ='Buy' then transaction_date end as BuyDate
   ,DATEDIFF(case when t.trans_type ='Sell' then transaction_date end
            ,case when t.trans_type ='Buy' then transaction_date end) as Date
   ,transaction_date
FROM transactions t
order by transaction_date
```

But always getting NULL in Date

Here is the complete query

```
SELECT p.abbreviation,ag.name
  ,sum(-1.00 * t.miles * t.price - coalesce(t.fees,0) - coalesce(c.cost,0)) as profit
  ,sum(t.miles) 'Totakl Miles'
  ,avg(price / miles) 'Average'
  ,transaction_date
FROM transactions t
inner join accounts a on t.account_id = a.id
inner join programs p on a.program_id = p.id
inner join agents ag on t.agent_id = ag.id
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT rp.sell_id, sum(rp.miles * t.price) as cost
           from report_profit rp
           inner join transactions t on rp.buy_id = t.id
           where t.miles > 50000
           group by rp.sell_id
           order by rp.sell_id
          ) c on t.id = c.sell_id
where t.transaction_date BETWEEN '2012-03-14' AND '2012-04-14'
Group by p.id , ag.id
```

**EDIT**

I tried liquorvicar answer, but it is giving error "Sub-query return more than one record" because of the Group by i added

Any one can guide me on this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Got an example query and result? You need to pass 2 arguments to DATEDIFF, from the way this looks to me you're only passing 1 argument into DATEDIFF because your case statement will yield only one date.

Comment: That's because you're only operating on a single row at a time, which means your `datediff` is always getting a `null` for one of the dates. You'll need a self join on `transactions` to match Buy records with Sell records.

Comment: You do not appear to have any key that relates the buy and sell transactions. How do you know which sell transaction relates to which buy transaction?

Comment: yes you all are right...

Comment: Adding the structures for all the tables involved would be quite helpful. Even better would be to include some sample data for each table and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for adding all the detail. Please humour me by adding the result that you expect from your query given the sample data that you have included. I cannot look at it right now but will check back in a couple of hours.

Comment: @nnichols , i need days transaction is in inventory, means (Sell date)2012-03-10 - (Buy date)2012-02-08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all thanks all for every help

Here is the query which return exact result

```
select p_id,ag_id,
     p_abb,ag_name
    ,sum(-1.00 * miles * price - coalesce(fees,0) - coalesce(cost,0)) as profit
    ,sum(miles) 'Total Miles',avg(price / miles) 'Average'
    ,DATEDIFF(min(buy_dt),min(sell_dt)) as 'Days'
     From
     (
         SELECT p.id 'p_id',ag.id 'ag_id',p.abbreviation 'p_abb',ag.name 'ag_name'
         ,miles
         ,price
         ,fees
         ,c.cost
         ,case when t.trans_type ='Sell' then transaction_date end 'sell_dt'
         ,case when t.trans_type ='Buy' then transaction_date end 'buy_dt'
         ,transaction_date
       FROM transactions t
       inner join accounts a on t.account_id = a.id
       inner join programs p on a.program_id = p.id
       inner join agents ag on t.agent_id = ag.id
       LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT rp.sell_id, sum(rp.miles * t.price) as cost
           from report_profit rp
           inner join transactions t on rp.buy_id = t.id
           where t.miles > 50000
           group by rp.sell_id
           order by rp.sell_id
          ) c on t.id = c.sell_id

  ) t1
  group by p_id, ag_id
```

Thanks all again..

Answer (score 1):

Try sub-queries like this

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(
      (
      SELECT MIN(date)
      FROM Transaction
      WHERE trans_type='Sell'
      ) AS first_sell_date
   ,
      (
      SELECT MIN(date)
      FROM Transaction
      WHERE trans_type='Buy'
      ) AS first_buy_date
   )
```

EDIT: Following OP comments and updating question with full query.

Can you not just wrap the DATEDIFF round a MIN call?

```
DATEDIFF(
    MIN(case when t.trans_type ='Sell' then transaction_date end),
    MIN(case when t.trans_type ='Buy' then transaction_date end)
) as Date
```

Comment: liquorvicar , thanks for your reply, but is there any other better way, actually i have lot of data to fetch with many joins

Comment: If your query is far more complex you need to include the details in your question. We are not mind readers, at least I'm not :)

Comment: @liquorvicar , using DATEDIFF as you mentioned in edit, giving Nulll for date

Comment: @AnilD Does every row have a correct date value (i.e. one that isn't 0000-00-00). I ran a similar query on a dataset I have where some of the dates were '0000-00-00' and it returned NULL. Excluding those values and it worked fine.

Comment: No. all date must have some value, but the case is same as it was in my first query, when case is Sell, Buy record will have null date and vice versa.

Comment: @AnilD NULLs shouldn't affect the MIN as long as there is one valid date in each group. I mimicked this behaviour where each row matched either condition and hence the other condition would be NULL, and wrapped that in DATEDIFF(MIN()) and it worked OK for me. Have you double checked no 0000-00-00 date values have snuck in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(sale.transaction_data, purchase.transaction_date)
FROM transactions purchase
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM transactions
    WHERE trans_type = 'Sell'
    ORDER BY transaction_date ASC
) sale
    ON purchase.transaction_date < sale.transaction_date
WHERE purchase.trans_type = 'Buy'
GROUP BY purchase.transaction_date
```

This will link all buy transactions to the next sell transaction based on date.

Or maybe something like this -

```
SELECT DATEDIFF((SELECT MIN(transaction_date)
                 FROM transactions t
                 WHERE t.trans_type = 'Sell'
                 AND t.transaction_date > purchase.transaction_date),
            purchase.transaction_date)
FROM transactions purchase
WHERE trans_type = 'Buy'
```