# How to add where clause and how to get the month difference of two dates

Tags: php, mysql

How to count columns when parapameter?

I need to count all clients which when you subtract todays date/current(ex; 2013-10-28) to birth_date column(ex; 2001-15-13) returns "<= 6 months"

I have a this mysql query:

```
$query = 'SELECT  b.record_number,
CONCAT(b.fname," ",b.lname) AS fullname,
province.area_name AS province,
district.area_name AS district,
llg.area_name AS llg,
office.area_name AS office, 
c.clinic_name,
a.feeding_type, 
COUNT(NOW, b.date_birth), - this is my code
b.date_birth,               
FROM tbl_records AS a
JOIN tbl_client AS b ON a.client_id = b.ID
JOIN tbl_clinic AS c ON a.clinic_id = c.ID
JOIN tbl_area AS llg ON c.llg_id = llg.ID
JOIN tbl_area AS district ON llg.parent_ids = district.ID
JOIN tbl_area AS province ON district.parent_ids = province.ID 
JOIN tbl_area AS office ON office.ID = a.office_id
WHERE a.date >= :start_date AND a.date <= :end_date 
AND a.feeding_type <> "NULL" AND a.office_id = :office_id
GROUP BY a.client_id';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL Query to get date difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140227/mysql-query-to-get-date-difference)

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between dates in MYSQL, you can use `DATEDIFF`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

From your question, I think that you are trying to return some intervals and return a string based on that interval.  You will need to set up a series of `IF` statements.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

UPDATE:

You can get the difference in months with `PERIOD-DIFF` but you will need to change the format of the dates.  Which you can do using `GET_FORMAT`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. but, how to format DATEDIFF function to return months, I have it but only returns day. Thank you

Comment: see update. Check the manual page that I have referenced.  That should give you an idea of things to do with a date.